# Ruby Module's included hook instead of regular extending?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, metaprogramming

There is a general way of adding class methods from Module via its included hook, and following extending base class with ClassMethods submodule. This way is described in book "Metaprogramming Ruby 2: Program Like the Ruby Pros". Here is an example from there:

```
module CheckedAttributes

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods

    def attr_checked(attribute, &validation)

      define_method "#{attribute}=" do |value|
        raise 'Invalid attribute' unless validation.call(value)
        instance_variable_set("@#{attribute}", value)
      end

      define_method attribute do
        instance_variable_get "@#{attribute}"
      end
    end
  end
end

class Person
  include CheckedAttributes
  attr_checked :age do |v|
    v >= 18
  end
end
```

But what is the reason of including the almost empty module first, and then extending its includer with one more module? Why not extend the class right the way with target module itself?

```
module CheckedAttributes

  def attr_checked(attribute, &validation)

    define_method "#{attribute}=" do |value|
      raise 'Invalid attribute' unless validation.call(value)
      instance_variable_set("@#{attribute}", value)
    end

    define_method attribute do
      instance_variable_get "@#{attribute}"
    end
  end
end

class Person
  extend CheckedAttributes

  attr_checked :age do |v|
    v >= 18
  end
end
```

Is code above totally equal to initial example from this book? Or there are any pitfalls?

Comment: Your example code never includes `CheckedAttributes` and hence the question is slightly irrelevant to the code shown.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Thanks, I've fixed a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea where you took this code from, but this pattern involving `ClassMethods` is normally used in the cases when you want to alter *both* class and eigenclass to avoid the necessity to call both `include Foo` and `extend Bar`.

```rb
module Named
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  def describe
    "Person is: #{name}"
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def name!
      define_method "name=" do |value|
        raise 'Invalid attribute' unless validation.call(value)
        instance_variable_set("@name", value)
      end

      define_method "name" do
        instance_variable_get "@name"
      end
    end
  end
end

class Person
  include Named
  name!
end

p = Person.new
p.name = "Trump"
p.describe #⇒ "Person is: Trump"
```

In your example, it makes zero sense.

Comment: *"In your example, it makes zero sense."* I have seen this adopted as a pattern where by all modules are to take this form so that adding instance methods, and/or class instance methods, later has a formal structure. I have even seen it taken 1 ugly step further with `ClassMethods` and `InstanceMethods` being encapsulated in the module